# Part of the body going off-screen

Tags: html, css, web

I've been working upon a Personal Portfolio for a few days now. I originally made it for my freeCodeCamp certification. But, now I wish to expand it however I've been facing a strange issue with the page where part of the body goes off-screen. I've tried resizing and removing the height of various elements and changed their display and position properties. But it's not working. I mean, it's not the biggest problem since all text and images are visible but still it's annoying.

I've hosted it through Github Pages here is the link:

brainstormed.github.io

It would be of great help if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed padding of 40px on `projectTile` CSS class is causing the issue. On small screens the horizontal space is already filled by the image `width: 80vw; padding: 10px; margin: 20px`. You can either remove that padding or use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to remove it on small screen sizes.